# Appending text to a listview in JFX

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I'm having trouble appending a username to a listview. I create users in one controller, while calling a method from another controller which appends the newly created username to a listview, but there's multiple runtime errors.

Method of adding users in the first controller:

```
void addUser(ActionEvent event) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername(newUserField.getText());
    user.setPassword(newPassField.getText());
    UserDAO theDAO = new UserDAO();
    theDAO.createUser(user);
    MainPanelAdminController mc = new MainPanelAdminController();
    mc.appendList(user.getUsername())
}
```

And this is the append method in the second controller:

```
void appendList(String username) {
    Label lbl = new Label(username);
    ObservableList<Label> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(lbl);
    listView.setItems(items);
}
```

Note: The `setUsername()`, `setPassword()`, `createUser()` and `getUsername()` methods are all working; the issue comes about at `listView.setItems(items)` - I added debugging lines to check.

Right now when I add a user it gives this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   Admin.panel.MainPanelAdminController.appendList(MainPanelAdminController.java:61)
>     at
>   Admin.panel.createUserController.addUser(createUserController.java:35)
>     ... 58 more
>
> **Line 61:** `listView.setItems(items);`
>   **Line 35:** `mc.appendList(user.getUsername());`

Comment: what is `listView` at line 61? is that even intialised?

Comment: @nullpointer `@FXML
    private JFXListView<Label> listView;` in MainPanelAdminController.java